# Could not load file or assembly - working on local not on production - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, web-deployment

I have this problem, where the project works fine on local, it just doesn't wortk on production

on local, everything works on IIS Express

on production, IIS 7.5, windows 2008 r2:

```
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.OpenAccess, Version=2014.3.1209.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (\\xxx\xxx\xxx\web.config line 106)
```

1. checked the file versions physically in the locaiton, they are present and correct
2. deleted the complete folder from production, then deployed
3. checked and ticked 32-bit applicaiton compatibility on IIS

also note that we had a previous version of the project deployed on production ( with same referenced files and versions) - only the target .net version has been changed and it stopped working (it's still targetting the same assembly, and works on local)

the files are there and all references in the referenced projects are correct for this file

what else can I look into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as it turns out - 
is as follows:

- although we had deleted the bin directory form the project output and re-built - it had no effect
- solution was to clean all the solution, then rebuild

obvious should have tried that , but sometimes your mind doesn't work :)